# How to read text file into python

Tags: python

Struggle with importing data. What am I doing wrong?
I have started my code with:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

open("dbfs/FileStore/shared_uploads/ebXXXXX.com/modified_uverse_data.txt") as mytxt:
  line in mytxt:
    print (line)
```

I receive a syntax error. My sample code looks like:

```
1|47|C|1|0|0|0|0|0

1|51|D|0|0|0|0|0|0

1|26|9|0|0|0|0|0|0
```

I am working to make column titles

```
PERSON_GENDER_CD| PERSON_AGE_NBR| HOUSEHOLD_INCOME_ID | DOG_WHISPERER| DOGS_101|BAD_DOG|PUPPIES_VS_BABIES|PUPPY_BOWL
```

Comment: What is the syntax error?

Comment: You need to use the `with` keyword: `with open(...) as mytxt:`

Comment: You'd better read again your tutorials, documentations and examples. Your current code actually contains syntax errors because what you have written is not correct Python. We could probably fix it for you, but my opinion is that it would be much better for you to learn the basics of Python first...

Comment: invalid syntax:  open("dbfs/FileStore/shared_uploads/ebxxxx@xxx.com/modified_uverse_data.txt") as mytxt:

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `with` keyword when opening a file "as" a variable.  Also, you need to include the `for` keyword in your loop.

```
with open(...) as mytxt:
    for line in mytxt:
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
mytxt = open("dbfs/FileStore/shared_uploads/ebXXXXX.com/modified_uverse_data.txt", "r")
for line in mytxt:
    print(line)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It’s syntax, not much to explain other than an example

Comment: Where are the synax error? Why do this way instead of using `as mytxt`?

Comment: user stated the syntax error above, and I don't use 'as mytxt' because I prefer the method I posted in my answer

Comment: So, maybe you should put this in the answer.

Comment: Put that I prefer my own answer????? lol